# In Jquery Ajax ,Get Response value as corresponding function return value

Tags: jquery

In Jquery Ajax ,Can we get response value as corresponding function return value

```
    checkSucess = function() {

        // Jquery Ajax with url,params and response
          doPost('sucess.php',
            'first=' + first,
           function(response) {

           });

       return response;// 'response' here is the value of response
```

How to return ajax response value of a function ,which is called from other function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when it's asynchronus you can't do it the way you want
if your sure that it the request will not last very long then make it async: false and see

```
checkSucess = function() {
  var result;

  //make it synchronus
  $.ajaxSetup({async:false});

  doPost('sucess.php',
        'first=' + first,
       function(response) {
          //get the response
          result = response;
       });

  //make it asynchronus
  $.ajaxSetup({async:true});

  return result;
}
```

Comment: If request takes too long ,then what would be result ?

Comment: the user navigator will hang for a while !!
we gotta try to make a better workaround

Answer (score 0):

You could define some global variable and assign the ajax response to it:

```
var someGlobal;
checkSucess = function() {

        // Jquery Ajax with url,params and response
          doPost('sucess.php',
            'first=' + first,
           function(response) {
                someGlobal = response;
           });
          return someGlobal;
```

Does this work for you